# Generating Salts, Silex, Charset?

Tags: php, salt, silex

I've been researching the best way to generate salts. General advice seems to be to use mcrype_create_iv or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes to generate. T

he problem with this is I have trouble using the values retrieved because of the characters involved. I am using RedBean as an ORM and and Silex as a framework. I have trouble setting and retrieving the generated value with RedBean, and I know Silex also has limitations because I received an error once that the salt can not contain brakets "{}".

What the best way to generate a salt that uses a standard character set. I figured I might be able to md5 the result, but then that results in a much smaller charset.

Comment: Do you know the alphabeth of accepted characters, could you provide it in your question?

Comment: I can't find any documentation on that. I was going for all standard lowercase/uppercase letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a valid salt, one has to know which algorithm will use this salt. Often you can use the function `base64_encode()` to retrieve standard characters from a binary salt, it will generate a string with following alphabet:

`base64 encoding alphabeth: +/0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

If Silex uses the salt for a BCrypt hash algoritm, it will expect a salt with following alphabet, note the "." instead of "+":

`BCrypt hash alphabet: ./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

I think it's best to test out what characters are allowed, or to find out which algorithm will be used, otherwise you will sooner or later generate an invalid salt. An example for generating a BCrypt salt using the function `mcrypt_create_iv()` could look like this:

```
/**
 * Generates a random salt for using with the BCrypt algorithm.
 * @param int $length Number of characters the string should have.
 * @return string A random salt.
 */
function sto_generateRandomSalt($length = 22)
{
  if (!defined('MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM')) die('The MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM source is required (PHP 5.3).');

  // Generate random bytes, using the operating system's random source.
  // Since PHP 5.3 this also uses the random source on a Windows server.
  // Unlike /dev/random, the /dev/urandom does not block the server, if
  // there is not enough entropy available.
  $randomBinaryString = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

  // BCrypt expects nearly the same alphabet as base64_encode returns,
  // but instead of the '+' characters it accepts '.' characters.
  // BCrypt alphabet: ./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  $randomEncodedString = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($randomBinaryString));
  return substr($randomEncodedString, 0, $length);
}
```